# What's the difference between these conditions?

Tags: ruby

Is there any specific difference between these conditions?

```
1) 
   begin
     acct = 1
     return 0
   end unless self.l_acct.nil?

2)
   unless self.l_acct.nil? 
     acct = 1
     return 0
   end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; the former is bad practice, the latter is not. They both accomplish the same thing.